# LINQ to Entities: All method not yielding the expected result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a pretty simple helper method to generate a unique code. To ensure that codes are unique I execute a LINQ to Entities query to verify that it isn't already in use.

My first attempt at writing this method worked perfectly:

```
public string GenerateUniqueSignUpCode()
{
    while( true )
    {
        var code = Path.GetRandomFileName().Substring( 0, 6 ).ToUpper();
        if( !Context.Users.Any(e => e.SignUpCode.ToUpper() == code) )
            return code;
    }
}
```

However, R# suggested that the LINQ expression could be simplified, which resulted in this method:

```
public string GenerateUniqueSignUpCode()
{
    while( true )
    {
        var code = Path.GetRandomFileName().Substring( 0, 6 ).ToUpper();
        if( Context.Users.All(e => e.SignUpCode.ToUpper() != code) )
            return code;
    }
}
```

This rewrite causes an infinite loop. The database does not contain any 6-character codes when the code is run so it should exit the loop on the first attempt (as does the first method shown).

Is All broken in EF 4.3.1 or what's going on?

Comment: If Jon's right, and this turns out to be a mis-refactor by R# then I suggest you report it to them too. Although I realise it may to be difficult to spot when a condition like this is evaluated as SQL instead!

Comment: I suppose it's a common enough case that they might consider it - will add an issue for it and see what happens.

Comment: Issue added: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-297527

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this will happen if `SignupCode` is null for any entry. The comparison using `!=` won't give a "true" result, so `All` will return false.

Just a guess, but it's the kind of thing I've seen before. You could try:

```
if (Context.Users.All(e => e.SignUpCode == null ||
                           e.SignUpCode.ToUpper() != code))
```

Comment: You're quite right - adding the null check makes it work. Not particularly intuitive that this is required though.

Comment: @MortenMertner: Nope, I'd agree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

`Context.Users.All(e => e.SignUpCode.ToUpper() != code`
should throw null reference exception if SignUpCode is null.

I guess expression is all fine. Data behind should have the problem

Comment: "should throw null reference exception if SignUpCode is null" if the expression is evaluated in C#, yes - but it's probably being transformed into SQL for evaluation which changes the null-handling semantics.